# java spring rabbit - gracefully reject a message

Tags: java, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I have the following listener method:

```
@Override
public void onMessage(Message message, Channel channel) {
  try {
    // do something bad :)
  } catch (Exception e){
    try {
      long dt = null != message.getMessageProperties() 
          ? message.getMessageProperties().getDeliveryTag() 
          : 0;
      channel.basicReject(dt, true);
    } catch(IOException io) {
      logger.error("IO-COMMON", io);
    }
  }
}
```

The issue is basic reject doesn't work, I don't know why. How to reject it gracefully? I think that if I reject a message, it should be requeued and reside is sth like cache, before going to next worker. But in fact this message just seems to be lost.

Comment: 1. Spaces. Around. Operators. It is a thing everyone has agreed on. 2. Why is your ternary so spaced out? The style I typically see, when it's not on one line, is `condition\n? if-true\n: if-false;`

Comment: Sorry, I can fix it if you'd like, I just wanted to emphasize the delivery tag line. Thanks

Comment: The style I mentioned above still has it on one line by itself -- notice the `\n`s to represent new lines -- and if you want to emphasize it, you can put a comment explaining what's important about it next to it. The spaces around operators thing is just for readability but it makes a huge difference when debugging, so it's a good habit to get into.

Comment: Ok, I will fix, thank you

Comment: "reside is sth like cache" ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to set the acknowledgemode to MANUAL if you are doing your own acks. I am not sure why it's not working for you; DEBUG/TRACE logging might help.

You should consider letting the container handle the acks - use `acknowledgemode=AUTO`; the container will normally requeue the message for any exception thrown or ack it if the listener returns normally.

You can set `defaultRequeueRejected` to false (it is true by default) and the message will be discarded (or routed to a DLX/DLQ).

You can also throw an `AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException` to override the default mechanism of requeuing failed messages.

If the ack mode is NONE - there are no acks and RabbitMQ automatically acks the message as soon as it's sent.

Comment: Thank you Gary, sorry, probably I mixed up the things, but I need my messages to stay in queue in case of exception. They should not be gone, but just waiting in queue for consumer to be fixed. I thought that reject should do the trick. It's like saying 'sorry, I am too busy, stay there and wait for me'. If I'm wrong, please correct me. The last thing I want it's to lose messages

Comment: If you set the ackmod to auto and throw the exception to the container (from your listener), the message will be requeued by default (and continually re-delivered). The container does the `basicReject(tag, true)` for you.

Comment: Yes, I saw it in my application, but if I wrap the code in try catch and reject manually, messages seems to be lost. Thank you